# Generate Typescript union from OpenAPI 3.0.0 spec using openapi-generator?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Currently using `3.0.3` of the OpenAPI spec, because that's that latest that version `6.0.0` of [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) supports at this time.

We generate `typescript` for the app browser client and `java` for the server.

Current OpenAPI spec, that generates a `status` field of type string:

```yaml
    UpdateAuthzResponse:
      description: > 
        'APPROVED' or 'REQUESTED'
      type: object
      required: [status]
      properties:
        status: {type: string}
```

For `typescript` this currently generates something like:

```ts
export interface UpdateAuthzResponse {
    status: string;
}
```

Is there an OpenAPI 3.0.0 spec that would generate a Typescript union *using the openapi-generator*? Something like:

```ts
export interface UpdateAuthzResponse {
    status: 'APPROVED' | 'REQUESTED';
}
```

I guess it would just generate an `enum` on `java` side.

I'm not looking to change the tool we use on the `typescript` side at the moment.  We may do that later, but this question is specifically about `openapi-generator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in answer by `dcstraw`, the openapi should look like this (I have modelled the status as a separate object):

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    AuthzRequestStatus:
      type: string
      enum: ['APPROVED', 'REQUESTED', 'REJECTED']
```

But the `stringEnums` flag (regardless of value being `"true"` or `"false"`) was causing `openapi-generator` to generate code like:

```ts
export enum AuthzRequestStatus {
    Approved = 'APPROVED',
    Requested = 'REQUESTED',
    Rejected = 'REJECTED'
}
```

When I removed the `stringEnums` flag entirely from my configuration, openapi-generator generated this:

```ts
export const AuthzRequestStatus = {
    Approved: 'APPROVED',
    Requested: 'REQUESTED',
    Rejected: 'REJECTED'
} as const;
export type AuthzRequestStatus = typeof AuthzRequestStatus[keyof typeof AuthzRequestStatus];
```

Which is roughly what I wanted (I expected it to just generate a union type directly, but building the union off the keys of the enum works fine for me, so good enough).

openapi-generator config can be found here if interested: https://github.com/au-research/raido-v2/blob/475adbdaf2f78095dbe30ddbb1c3cc3e6511a048/app-client/build.gradle#L26

Usage of the generated type: https://github.com/au-research/raido-v2/blob/475adbdaf2f78095dbe30ddbb1c3cc3e6511a048/app-client/src/Page/Admin/AuthzRespondPage.tsx#L119

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `enum` property to `status` in your spec, openapi-generator should produce a type that restricts the possible values, i.e. change this:

```yaml
status: {type: string}
```

to:

```yaml
status:
  type: string
  enum:
    - APPROVED
    - REQUESTED
```

In some of the generators, you can further control what kind of type is produced (union type vs. enum) using the `stringEnums` option.